# @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The address provided as argument contains a contract, but its bytecode doesn't match any of your local contracts

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I deployed a contract with proxy implementation with hardhat:

This is the hardhat/script:

const { ethers, upgrades } = require("hardhat");

```
async function main() {
  const Test = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test");
  console.log("Deploying Test...");
  const box = await upgrades.deployProxy(Test, [10], {
    initializer: "initialize",
  });
  await box.deployed();
}

main();
```

When you run a transaction to deploy a contract, we actually deploy 3 contracts:

- Implementation Contract, in this case my simple custom Test conract
- Proxy Admin contract
- TransparentUpgradeableProxy

I successfully verified "Implementation" and "TransparentUpgradeableProxy" contract. That means my hardhat config and script are correct. But I get the error when I verify the `ProxyAdmin` contract.

```
// I load the environment variables from .env
env $(cat .env) npx hardhat verify --network goerli 0x45a87e0E632a4C269De0FEE6a6FbABF7B4f8b92d
```

This is the error:

> Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The address provided as
> argument contains a contract, but its bytecode doesn't match any of
> your local contracts.
>
> Possible causes are:
>
> - Contract code changed after the deployment was executed. This includes code for seemingly unrelated contracts.
> - A solidity file was added, moved, deleted or renamed after the deployment was executed. This includes files for seemingly unrelated
>   contracts.
> - Solidity compiler settings were modified after the deployment was executed (like the optimizer, target EVM, etc.).
> - The given address is wrong.
> - The selected network (goerli) is wrong.

Since it says "its bytecode doesn't match any of your local contracts", I added this contract into the contracts directory

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/beacon/BeaconProxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/beacon/UpgradeableBeacon.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Proxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/TransparentUpgradeableProxy.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/transparent/ProxyAdmin.sol";

// Kept for backwards compatibility with older versions of Hardhat and Truffle plugins.
contract AdminUpgradeabilityProxy is TransparentUpgradeableProxy {
    constructor(
        address logic,
        address admin,
        bytes memory data
    ) payable TransparentUpgradeableProxy(logic, admin, data) {}
}
```

But still same error:

Comment: As per my experience, you do not need to verify the proxy admin contract when deploying using hardhat upgrades, it is verified by default. I've checked it on goerli and apparently it is already verified too. 
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x45a87e0E632a4C269De0FEE6a6FbABF7B4f8b92d

Comment: I am curious why it says " its bytecode doesn't match any of your local contracts". it should just have said, "this contract is already verified"

Comment: prolly that's because it is from node_module/@openzeppelin, not from your local directory i.e that is inside the contracts folder of hh. generally, the artifacts are not built for every file of node module. I recently got to know this when I was using @onchain-id, artifacts for identity proxy were missing. Then I added that to local hh dir but still was having issues then tried flattening the imports in one file and finally, and put it in the contracts folder of hh and it worked.